# Noise is a form of dissipation?

Tags: energy, noise, dissipation

(Mechanical) noise is a form of dissipation? For example, when the computer fan turns it produces noise. This noise is a form of dissipation in addition to heat produced by the machine (computer)? If yes, how introduce this noise in energy balance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mechanical noise is a form of energy loss, which ultimately also will end as heat: the acoustic waves will be absorbed by different kinds of substances which will vibrate more causing friction which will ultimately cause a temperature rise.

Note that the acoustic power is often extremely low, often no more than a few mW, and when those get absorbed by a total mass of tens or hundreds of kg you can imagine that the temperature rise won't be high. For instance a bucket of water needs 10 mW during 10 hours to see a 0.01 °C rise.